# how to set pygtk scrolledwindow vscrollbar at bottom

Tags: python, linux, pygtk

I am using a python 2.5 + pygtk.
I have added a text area in a scrolled window. Text area buffer will be updates with program output.

I want to set scrolledwindow->vscrollbar at the bottom.

I tried different options given in pygtk docs. But no success..

Any suggestion what needs to do???

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the vertical [adjustment](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkadjustment.html) of your scrolled window, then set its [value](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkadjustment.html#method-gtkadjustment--set-value) to its [upper bound](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkadjustment.html#method-gtkadjustment--get-upper):

```
adjustment = yourScrolledWindow.get_vadjustment()
adjustment.set_value(adjustment.get_upper())
```

Comment: I am trying same thing... but its giving error 
AttributeError: 'gtk.Adjustment' object has no attribute 'get_upper'

Comment: @rohan, can you provide the error you receive and its stack trace?